# Facebook Audience Network: Estimated Payout not showning in Payout section

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, google-play, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Network to Monetize Android applications.
My estimated revenue for month of November is greater than $150 but even till 5th of December of next month still "No result Found" in Estimated payouts in payout section.
Can anyone help whether it's any technical issue or other. 
best regards,

Comment: hi @AAhmad Bilal i have the same issue did you get your payout or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically show after 7th or 8th of month. It there is a weekend on said date then revenue will show on coming working day.